# How to filter with different conditions?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Here I am trying to filter staffs by three conditions by selecting joined date year,month and organization.And for this I have tried like this but it is not working .What I am doing wrong here ?

```
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

And also I find this method that I tried below too long for my problem.If there any better solution for this then it would be a great help

models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                     related_name='staff')
    joined_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

```
def filter_staff_users(request):
    year = request.GET.get('year')
    month = request.GET.get('month')
    organization = request.GET.get('organization')
    present_year = datetime.datetime.today().year
    years_list = range(2016,present_year + 1)

    if year or month or organization:
        staffs = Staff.objects.filter(
            Q(joined_date__year=year) | Q(joined_date__month=month) | Q(organization=organization))
        return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                      {'years_list': years_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                       'organization': organization})
    elif year and month and organization:
        staffs = Staff.objects.filter(Q(joined_date__year=year), Q(joined_date__month=month),
                                      Q(organization=organization))
        return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                      {'years_list': years_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                       'organization': organization})

    elif year:
        staffs = Staff.objects.filter(joined_date__year=year)
        return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                      {'years_list': years_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                       'organization': organization})

    elif month:
        staffs = Staff.objects.filter(joined_date__month=month)
        return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                      {'years_list': years_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                       'organization': organization})

    elif organization:
        staffs = Staff.objects.filter(organization=organization)
        return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                      {'years_list': rangeyears_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                       'organization': organization})

    else:
        messages.info(request, 'Nothing selected to filter.')
        return redirect('organization:view_staff_users')
```

template

```
<form action="{% url 'organization:filter_staffs' %}" class='form-inline' >

                   <select name="year">
                       <option value="">Select Year</option>
                    {% for year in years_list %}
                       <option value="{{year}}">
                       {{year}}
                       </option>
                       {% endfor %}

                   </select>
          <select  name="month" >
            <option >Select Month</option>
            <option value="01">January</option>
            #months names here

          </select>

            <select name="organization">

                       <option value="">Select Organization</option>
                 {% for organization in organizations %}
                       <option value="{{organization.pk}}">{{organization.name}}</option>
                {% endfor %}

                   </select>


        <div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Find Staffs</button>
        </div>

      </form>
```

Full Traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /organization/filter/all/staffs/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\VzealProjects\StaffMgmt\organization\views.py", line 321, in filter_staff_users
    Q(joined_date__year=year) | Q(joined_date__month=month) | Q(organization=organization))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 844, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 862, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1263, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1281, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq,
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1225, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1096, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\lookups.py", line 70, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1807, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
[11/Sep/2019 12:47:31] "GET /organization/filter/all/staffs/?year=&month=Select+Month&organization= HTTP/1.1" 500 121189
```

Comment: Can you show the full error trace please.

Comment: @DanielHolmes added

Comment: can you add your Staff model?

Comment: @NalinDobhal yes added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first if block doesn't make much sense. You check `year or month or organization`, ie if *any* of them are non-empty, but then proceed to filter on *all* of them with `Q(joined_date__year=year) | Q(joined_date__month=month) | Q(organization=organization)`; if any of them are actually blank you will get that error.

I can't tell what you are trying to do in that block, but you should probably just remove it, given that you handle the other combinations in the other blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem where I have to build a filter dynamically based on available data. I ended up with similar to the following: (Untested code, to give you an idea)

```
    filters = Q()

    if year is not None:
        filters = filters & Q(joined_date__year=year)

    if month is not None:
        filters = filters & Q(joined_date__month=month)

    if organization is not None:
        filters = filters & Q(organization=organization)

    staffs = Staff.objects.filter( filters )
    return render(request, 'organization/view_staff_users.html',
                  {'years_list': years_list, 'staffs': staffs, 'year': year, 'month': month,
                   'organization': organization})
```

In above code, the fields which have values will be added up to the `filters` variable which we will be using to fetch values from `Staff` model. This way all your conditions will be minimized.